# iterating over a sub array which is not aligned with the array axes

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, iteration

I have a 2D image which is represented as a linear array and if I know the numbers of rows and columns, I can access the pixel values.

So, assuming I have a column major array, I can get the pixel value as:

```
// image is an unsigned char array
unsigned char getValue(int row, int col)
{
    // Skipping the checks
    return image[row * NumCols + col];
}
```

Now, I would like to iterate over a sub-array of this array and this is also simple to do as long as I know the row and column offset.

```
unsigned char getValue(int row, int col, int offsetRow, int offsetCol)
{
     int index = (row + rowOffset) * NumCols + offsetCol + col;
     return image[index];
}
```

Now, I want to iterate over a sub array which is not aligned with the array axes i.e. think of it as a rotated subarray within the original array. So, I have access to the positions of the 4 corners of this array. What would be an efficient way to create an iterator for this rotated array?

I am guessing I will need to compute the slope of the four boundaries and based on that I need to check if a pixel is within this boundary or not. Another way I can think of is to compute a bounding box mask which can tell whether a pixel is within the sub array or not and iterate over that.

I wonder if there is more efficient way to do something like this especially using some STL magic.

Comment: For non trivial case, they are several algorithm to "draw" a line between 2 points which doesn't result exactly in same line...

Comment: @Jarod42 Have not thought about it in that much detail. Can you refer to a few by name. I would like to check them out. I thought in Euclidean geometry, you can only have one line between two points...

Comment: I doubt if `STL` algorithms will solve this. It seems like a question of solving the equations of the intersections of the bounding box lines of your rectangle and the horizontal lines of the array.

Comment: you need some strategy to decide what elements belong to the subarray and which dont, once you have this the rest is trivial

Comment: One constraint I have is that the points will always lie in the image plane and I think that means that the bounding box will also lie in the image plane. I will try and code something up heuristically and see if it works... and then iterate. I will update the tread

Comment: *" I thought in Euclidean geometry"* : We have to handle pixel, we are in discrete space, see [Line_drawing_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm).